# select folder path to save file

Tags: php, web-deployment

I am building an online storage site where users can upload their files (this part of the coding is done). After uploading files users must have an option to download them. this is where I'm stuck. I want to add code that will let my users see a dialog box saying to choose the path , where in the pc  the file will download. similar to this image (given in the link)

http://www.libraries.psu.edu/content/psul/cataloging/deptinfo/deptgroups/ecip/localsavefile/_jcr_content/openpar/textimage_psul_1/image.img.jpg/1369406997262.jpg

my question is, can I build this dialog box in php? if it is possible in php then what function do I need for coding. please say anything so that I can find a point to began with.

---thanks.

Comment: javascript is best option for this ..

Comment: but how ? can you explain with a code example? @Drudge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is something you (the programmer) don't have control over. When a file is downloaded by the browser, it's the browsers settings that define where the file is saved or if it's saved automatically w/o folder selection or lets the user select a target folder.

Comment: You are right! So that means I'd don't have to worry about where files are downloaded. It's Google chrome's job isn't it? @Marcell

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Users will worry about that. Anyway, it's their machine not yours... :)